# XAMPP server session not working

Tags: php, html

I have installed a XAMPP server on my MAC laptop.I am able to access my php files from an HTML request on my Laptop and $_SESSION is working if i use http://localhost.Things work as expected by persisting session information across php files.
My other friend who is on my LAN network tried to connect to my XAMPP server  php files using the same HTML files in his laptop.When ever he sends request $_SESSION[] is not working and am not getting data persisted across pages.HY other friend has enabled cookies on his browser too.He is using Safari too to connect.

Could you please tell what could be the issue?.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a session you have to give it the domain in which it will work. If you create the session using **localhost** as domain or **127.0.0.1** when your friend connects from the other computer in your LAN it will simply not work. Try using your LAN IP address to create the cookie

Comment: hi nicolas,thanks for your response.In my http.conf file its # XAMPP
ServerName localhost  - is this one which tells to create session as local host?.Could you please eloborate on your comment "Try using your LAN IP address to create the cookie" as i am new to web technologies and i was a strict C++ programmer til few months back.

Comment: Try "ipconfig" command if you are using windows. Or "ifconfig" command if using linux. You need the ip address your router is giving you. Mine for example is 192.168.0.101. That's the address you need when creating the cookie. (note that only people in your LAN will be able to use the cookie). Sorry for the delay